# VB6 SSTab event change while tab clicked

Tags: vb6

I'm using SSTab in vb6, and i have 2 tab : "Tab1","Tab2".

Which Tab1 have content such Frames,dll.

And Tab2 doesn't have content, then, i want while i clicked Tab "Tab2", it show another form, and didn't show blank content.
Like using Form.Show and Form.Hide function.

I searched from internet, and i've found this code:

```
Private Sub SSTab1_Click(PreviousTab As Integer)
    If SSTab1.Tab Then
        Form2.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Yes, it works, but the form will open when i click any tab, i want the form will open when i click "Tab2" tab, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub SSTab1_Click(PreviousTab As Integer)
Select Case SSTab1.Tab
Case 0
' your code

Case 1
' your code

Case 2
' your code
Form2.Show 
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but it seems, it still showing "Tab2" tab with blank content :(

Comment: do you mean, place form2 content in tab2 ?

Comment: no, when i click "Tab2" tab, it will show another form, and previous tab, so, "Tab2" tab's blank content will not showing